# How are df2 values placed to the right of df1 columns when there is a match in a common column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I want that for each row of `df_transformed` where there is a match with a row of the `Name` column with `df` we add the values of the `df_transformed` row to `df`.

I have an example dataframe `df` (actually there are other columns):

```
     Name
0    Wine Intelligence, Rapport 
1    .DS_Store
2    Chiffres 2021 mail
3    Chiffres 2021 rapport
4    Chiffres 2021 rapport
```

and `df_transformed`:

```
    Name                    Theme       Pays
0   Chiffres Rapport (pdf)  Expeditions [France, Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgi...
1   Image WI                Image       [ Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgique, Por...
2   Brand Power WI          Marques     [ Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgique, Por...
3   Volume WI               Achat       [ Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgique, Por...
4   Critères WI             Critères    [ Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgique, Por...
```

When I use `df_merged = df.merge(df_transformed, on='Name', how='left')`,  I get

```
    Name                        Theme       Pays
0   Wine Intelligence, Rapport  Expeditions [France, Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgi...
1   .DS_Store                   Image       [ Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgique, Por...
2   Chiffres 2021 mail          Marques     [ Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgique, Por...
3   Chiffres 2021 rapport       Achat       [ Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgique, Por...
4   Chiffres 2021 rapport       Critères    [ Allemagne, Italie, Espagne, Belgique, Por...
```

There is a problem, it looks like it added `df_transformed` values row by row, rather than only when columns `Name` match.
See, there is a problem: "Figures 2021 mail" has "Brands" in the Subject column when it is the one for "Brand Power WI".

Comment: that is odd.. i don't think this would be the issue but worth asking. in df_transformed the 'Name' column looks like its over the index rather than the names? in theory if it was merging on indexes the results would make sense so i'd make sure your column names and indexes aren't getting mixed somehow

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad layout @rayad Unfortunately Name column is actually over the names. I don't understand why it doesn't work. I don't know what to do as an alternative ...

Comment: Was worth a shot. I don't see anything wrong with it though.. Maybe try doing pd.merge(df1, df2, etc, etc)? I'm not sure if doing df1.merge() has different implications..